Why isn't an optional type/interface definition being respected in a .tsx React component?
Inside a file like Button.tsx, I define the props like this:
type ButtonProps = {
  label: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

However, my editor (Visual Studio Code) is telling me that disabled is boolean. Not boolean | undefined, which is what I expect because of the optional ?.
If I specify disabled: string | boolean, then my editor is happy to acknowledge that disabled is a string or a boolean. If I change it to string | undefined, it goes right back to thinking it's a string.
What am I doing wrong here?

In your tsconfig file, do you have either strictNullChecks or strict set to true?

@NicholasTower I have neither set.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "functions/**/*.*"
  ]
}


That's the reason then. If you don't have one of those set, typescript ignores nulls and undefineds. Of the two options, i recommend you use strict, since it adds other useful checks in addition to nulls and undefineds.
